# custom css on certain url Liquid Shopify

Tags: css, styles, shopify, liquid

I am trying to add css on **certain** URL Liquid Shopify. Only on that subpage I need that element in different style than other pages.
I found in the other liquid code some examples attached inside, but it is not working. Those are my examples I've tried:
The element I would like to style has no unique class or id.

```
<style>
{% if page.url == 'fullUrl' '%}
  #someEmelent {margin: 0 auto}
{% endif %}
{% if page.url == '/subpage/subpage' '%}
  #someEmelent {margin: 0 auto}
{% endif %}
{% if page.url == '/subpage' '%}
  #someEmelent {margin: 0 auto}
{% endif %}
</style>
```

I have tried other things in pure CSS, like:

```
@document url("http://www.example.com/subpade/") {
#someEmelent {margin: 0 auto}
}
```

Comment: If you can include JS, you can try adding a new class.

Comment: I will try, is anything else to use in Liquid or pure CSS?

Comment: If you send me the page link, I can help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use the request object:
https://shopify.dev/docs/themes/liquid/reference/objects/request#request-path

So something like this should work:

```
{% if request.path contains 'variable_part_of_url' %}
    <style>
        /* your styles */
    </style>
{% endif %}
```

Another way would be to create and apply a specific template to your page.
Then you might add a specific class to body and use it in your CSS file.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is to base your CSS on template title. ex: if you want to a  CSS class for a specific collection your can use :

```
class="{{ collection.title | handleize }}"
```

you can change collection  with any template name